# ASP.NET MVC 3 Telerik Razor grid with editable foreign key dropdown column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to create an Ajax Telerik grid in Razor that has an updateable foreign key column that shows a dropdown list. I've copied my page pretty much like the example, and everything works. I can add new records, delete them and edit them. The only thing that doesn't work is that I get a textfield with the integer when I update a record in my grid, instead of a dropdown list with all the possibilities of the foreign key table.

Anyone have any ideas on how I could fix this? See code below.

Telerik grid:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<EditableAccount>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-left:0" }))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Insert("InsertAccount", "Administration")
        .Update("SaveAccount", "Administration")
        .Delete("DeleteAccount", "Administration"))
    .DataKeys(keys => { keys.Add(a => a.AccountId); })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.ForeignKey(b => b.BankId, (IEnumerable)ViewData["Banks"], "ID", "Name").Width(50);
        columns.Bound(a => a.AccountNumber).Width(110);
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
            commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
        }).Width(16);
    })
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable()
)
```

Controller:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult Accounts()
{
    ViewData["Banks"] = db.Banks.Select(b => new { Id = b.BankId, Name = b.Name });
    return View(new GridModel(accountRepository.All()));
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult InsertAccount()
{
    //Create a new instance of the EditableProduct class.
    EditableAccount account = new EditableAccount();

    //Perform model binding (fill the product properties and validate it).
    if (TryUpdateModel(account))
    {
        //The model is valid - insert the product.
        accountRepository.Insert(account);
    }

    //Rebind the grid
    return View(new GridModel(accountRepository.All()));
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult SaveAccount(int id, int bankId)
{
    EditableAccount account = new EditableAccount
    {
        AccountId = id,
        Bank = db.Banks
                   .Where(b => b.BankId == bankId)
                   .Select(b => b.Name).SingleOrDefault(),
        BankId = bankId
    };

    TryUpdateModel(account);

    accountRepository.Update(account);

    return View(new GridModel(accountRepository.All()));
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult DeleteAccount(int id)
{
    //Find a customer with ProductID equal to the id action parameter
    EditableAccount account = accountRepository.One(a => a.AccountId == id);

    if (account != null)
    {
        //Delete the record
        accountRepository.Delete(account);
    }

    //Rebind the grid
    return View(new GridModel(accountRepository.All()));
}
```

Model:

```
public class EditableAccount
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UIHint("GridForeignKey")]
    [DisplayName("Bank")]
    public int BankId { get; set; }
    public string Bank { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("AccountNumber")]
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Repository:

```
public IList<EditableAccount> All()
{
    IList<EditableAccount> result =
            (from account in db.Accounts
             select new EditableAccount
             {
                 AccountId = account.AccountId,
                 Bank = account.Bank.Name,
                 BankId = account.BankId,
                 AccountNumber = account.AccountNr
             }).ToList();

    return result;
}

public EditableAccount One(Func<EditableAccount, bool> predicate)
{
    return All().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}

public void Insert(EditableAccount insertedAccount)
{
    Account account = new Account();
    account.BankId = insertedAccount.BankId;
    account.AccountNr = insertedAccount.AccountNumber;
    db.Accounts.InsertOnSubmit(account);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}

public void Update(EditableAccount updatedAccount)
{
    Account account = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AccountId == updatedAccount.AccountId);
    account.BankId = updatedAccount.BankId;
    account.AccountNr = updatedAccount.AccountNumber;
    db.SubmitChanges();
}

public void Delete(EditableAccount deletedAccount)
{
    Account account = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AccountId == deletedAccount.AccountId);
    db.Accounts.DeleteOnSubmit(account);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the forums at Telerik yet? I've personally never used the same situation that you are using but I've mostly had good luck with their support team, especially with their team member Atanas, he's pretty good with figuring out what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered my question on the Telerik forums:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/asp-net-mvc-razor-grid-with-editable-foreign-key-dropdown-column.aspx